# UILabel overlapping text in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a question. I have made a simple text and button app. When I touch the button and tell it to change the text in the label, the text overlaps.

I have made a simple app that says "hello Phylicia" in a `UILabel` and when the button is pressed it should change to "how are you". How do I get the text to change?

I am using this setup here:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var funFactLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func showFunFact() {
    funFactLabel.text = "How are you"
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct.  What do you mean by, "the text in the label the text overlaps"?  Can you post a screenshot of the problem in action and maybe what your storyboard looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the UILabel larger. "How are you" may extend further than "Hello Phylicia" and therefore would not fit inside the designated area.